# redirect every page to mobile view

Tags: php, url, redirect, mobile

I am working on a site and it has two templates, one for mobile devices and the main site view for pc users.

I already have a code in the index file of my site that will redirect users to root/m for mobile devices.

My problem is when working with links to specific pages/content, the user is redirected to the main page.

for example:

if a user visits `www.projectnaija.com/index.php?page=addtopic&cid=11` from a mobile device

he/she is redirected to `www.projectnaija.com/m`

I want the redirect to `www.projectnaija.com/m/index.php?page=addtopic&cid=11`

any idea or useful tip?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the url query of the link before redirecting. for example

www.projectnaija.com/index.php?page=addtopic&cid=11

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$redirectTo = "http://www.projectnaija.com/m/index.php?{$url}";
```

i am not sure the best way but this will work, i think